# Pug mixin -- Format html markup within a string

Tags: html, pug

I have a mixin that takes a `title` and `content`.

```
mixin card-header(title, content)
  .card.section
    .card-header.secondary-color.white-text
      h4.card-title= title
    .card-body
      p= content
```

When I use the mixin with just text It works fine, but when I add inline elements to the string such as `code`, `b`, `em`, etc. it doesn't create the tags it just displays the pug syntax.

```
+card-header('Page Header', 'I have #[b bold] text')
```

With that I would like the the output to be `I have <b>bold</b> text`
Instead it is creating `I have #[b bold] text`

What can I do to get the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually happening because special characters are by default getting an escape sequence replacement. Since you do not want that, simply replace p= content with p!= content.

So, make your pug code look like that:

```
mixin card-header(title, content)
  .card.section
    .card-header.secondary-color.white-text
      h4.card-title= title
    .card-body
      p!= content

+card-header('Page Header', 'I have <b>bold</b> text')
```

Comment: also, you are passing html to the mixin, it should be pug syntax

Answer (score 0):

The pug won't render the text twice, but you can put a block in your mixin like this:

```
mixin card-header(title, content)
    .card.section
        .card-header.secondary-color.white-text
            h4.card-title= title
        .card-body
            block

+card-header('Page Header')
    p I have #[b bold] text
```